# Take control of the hardware back button using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have gone through the following link and my situation is same like it.

*[Disable the hardware back function with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425820/disable-hardware-back-function-jquery-mobile)*

**Situation:** Device under test: [Samsung Galaxy S III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III)

Page A: ListView with Names(A1, A2, A3) 
Page B: Consist of a *Form*, *Submit* and *Cancel* button.

The user fills in the form and click on the *Submit* button. And his/her data gets uploaded to the server. The page is updated and a confirmation dialog is displayed that data is uploaded to the server.

**Now the issue arrives.**

Now when the user clicks on the *hardware* back button he/she is again redirected to Page B and he/she is again able to submit the form (which we don't require, as the form is meant to be filled only once).

So is there a way through which I can control the hardware back button to show Page A whenever it is on Page B?

The following answer from Nirmal seems to have answer, but I don't know how to implement it -

> There is no real way disable the hardware back button on the
> BlackBerry or Android.
>
> What you can do is maintain a session variable which gets invalidated
> in your back handler and check for that session variable in the
> pagebeforeshow event of the Exam page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Disable the hardware back function with jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425820/disable-the-hardware-back-function-with-jquery-mobile)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to capture the hardware back button click event with JavaScript:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27) {
    // Prevent default (disable the back button behavior)
    event.preventDefault();

    // Your code to show another page or whatever...
  }
});
```

Comment: I am working on Samsung galaxy S3 mobile, I guess this is for Keyboard

Comment: I have tested it with a Samsung GT-S5570 (without keyboard) and works.

Comment: Hi I am still having problem, could you please tell me where should i ass this code in my code.

Comment: Do it before loading jQueryMobile javascript file. Event should be bind to the `document`, so that it captures all events of `keydown` (and hardware back button should produce this event).

Comment: But it worked with a blackberry which has a bac button not with my Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830i. Anyways thanks for helping out.

Comment: For me it is working for both platforms (for Blackberry I have tested it in a 9810 device). I don't know any other way to do it... sorry I could not help more.

Comment: This event gets triggered on desktop browser when pressing the backspace key but not the back button on Galaxy Ace.  Desktop browser's graphical back button also does not trigger this event so can only guess that the Galaxy Ace's back button is the same as the browser's graphical back button.  Solution must be non-device/browser specific

Answer (score 2):

Use cookies. Whenever the form is processed, add a value to the user's cookie and on the form page check if that cookie value exists.

If it does, just show the user a message which indicates that the data have already been submitted or redirect the user to the main page.

Answer (score 1):

I included the Login form and the page the user is directed after login, in the same HTML file as two pages (multi-page containers).

After validating the login, I call the changePage to the id of the new page I want to load with **changeHash** as **false**. This way, the user won't be returned to the login even by the hardware back button.